# How to select an element which contains an specific subelement in XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

I have some MARC21-XML documents about books. I want to extract the names of the translators of the book.

Here is a snippet from one MARC21-XML document of a book:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <record xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim" type="Bibliographic">
    <datafield tag="700" ind1="1" ind2=" ">
      <subfield code="a">Wasel, Ulrike</subfield>
      <subfield code="4">trl</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield tag="700" ind1="1" ind2=" ">
      <subfield code="a">Timmermann, Klaus</subfield>
      <subfield code="4">trl</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield tag="700" ind1="1" ind2="2">
      <subfield code="a">Eggers, Dave</subfield>
    </datafield>
  </record>
```

*Dave Eggers* is the author of the book and *Klaus Timmermann* and *Ulrike Wasel* helped translating the book.

In this scenario the following "simple" XPath 2.0 expression would work to extract the "translators":

```
/record/datafield[@tag='700'][@ind1='1'][@ind2=' ']/subfield[@code='a']/text()
```

The result of this XPath 2.0 expression would be the following:

```
Text='Wasel, Ulrike'
Text='Timmermann, Klaus'
```

This seems to work nicely. **However**, I can think of a not-yet-discovered scenario in which there are additional elements with types other than translators (`subfield[@code='a'] = 'trl'`.

I would like to have the following selection logic implemented as XPath 2.0 but struggle to construct one:

- `/record/datafield` attribute `tag` has value "700"
- `/record/datafield` attribute `ind1` has value "1"
- `/record/datafield` attribute `ind2` has value " "
- `/record/datafield` contains `subfield` with attribute `code` equals "4" and its `text()` is "trl"

To mockup the scenario:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <record xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim" type="Bibliographic">
    <datafield tag="700" ind1="1" ind2=" ">
      <subfield code="a">Wasel, Ulrike</subfield>
      <subfield code="4">trl</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield tag="700" ind1="1" ind2=" ">
      <subfield code="a">Timmermann, Klaus</subfield>
      <subfield code="4">trl</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield tag="700" ind1="1" ind2=" ">
      <subfield code="a">Doe, John</subfield>
      <subfield code="4">oth</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield tag="700" ind1="1" ind2="2">
      <subfield code="a">Eggers, Dave</subfield>
    </datafield>
  </record>
```

In this scenario the following "simple" XPath 2.0 expression would work to extract the "translators":

```
/record/datafield[@tag='700'][@ind1='1'][@ind2=' ']/subfield[@code='a']/text()
```

The result of this XPath 2.0 expression would be the following:

```
Text='Wasel, Ulrike'
Text='Timmermann, Klaus'
Text='Doe, John'
```

And there is the error: *John Doe* is not a translator (`trl`) but some other (`oth`) contributor to the book. I do not want him ;)

I am not that familar to the MARC21-XML specification. The specifications about MARC21-XML which I have read are in a very strange tabular format that is hard to understand. It is possible that `@ind1='1'` and `@ind2=' '` contains only translators but than the "type" field with "trl" makes no sense.

**How to construct an XPath 2.0 expression that selects only the translators from the mockedup screnario?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To further restrict this XPath,

```
/record/datafield[@tag='700'][@ind1='1'][@ind2=' ']
       /subfield[@code='a']/text()
```

to select only those `datafield` elements whose `subfield` child element with `code` of `4` has a string value of `"trl"`, add another predicate, `[subfield[@code='4']='trl']`:

```
/record/datafield[@tag='700'][@ind1='1'][@ind2=' ']
                 [subfield[@code='4']='trl']
       /subfield[@code='a']/text()
```